# Video converter: ogv to avi (or another more common format)

Tags: video, conversion, recordmydesktop

I've been using recordMyDesktop to record stuff. A little slow to compile but it records fine. However, when I try to convert from ogv to avi (I've used Devede and an mencoder script) the audio and video go out of sync.

Here's the script for reference:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ogv to avi
# Call this with multiple arguments
# for example : ls *.{ogv,OGV} | xargs ogv2avi
N=$#;
echo "Converting $N files !"
for ((i=0; i<=(N-1); i++))
do
echo "converting" $1
filename=${1%.*}
#mencoder "$1" -ovc xvid -oac mp3lame -xvidencopts pass=1 -o $filename.avi
mencoder "$1" -o $filename.avi -oac mp3lame -lameopts fast:preset=standard -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:vbitrate=4000
shift 1
done
```

**Are there good reliable video converters out there? :)**

Comment: Similar question: http://askubuntu.com/q/1691/667

Comment: i'm thinking the asker might be trying to use the command from that QA and is having an issue so he asked a different question about the a/v sync

Comment: Yes, it's about sync issues. :)

Comment: Just picked an answer. I don't know why, but it seems that different things work for different setups. Sucks though that we have to do research regarding this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [winff](http://packages.ubuntu.com/winff) [image: Install winff]

Is a GUI for the command line video converter, FFMPEG. It will convert most any video file that FFmpeg will convert. WinFF does multiple files in multiple formats at one time. You can for example convert mpeg's, flv's, and mov's, all into avi's all at once.

Comment: This worked for me too. I suspect because it's FFMPEG just like http://askubuntu.com/questions/17309/video-converter-ogv-to-avi-or-another-more-common-format/17312#17312. I'm picking this though because it has the gui. Less for me to memorize!

Comment: WinFF is presently unusable on Ubuntu 14.04, it fails to find the libxvid encoder. There is a bug report on it: https://code.google.com/p/winff/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=168

Answer (score 7):

You can use **avconv** to **convert and optionally resize** (it is included with **ffmpeg**):

```
avconv -i "input.ogv" -vcodec mjpeg -acodec mp2 -s 640x480 -vb 3000k -ab 160k "output.avi"
```

This converts your video to a .avi file with mjpeg and mp2 codecs for good compatibility.

```
avconv -i "input.ogv" -vcodec mjpeg -acodec mp2 -s 640x480 -qscale 5 "output.avi"
```

This converts your video using quality scale.

Comment: This preserved the quality the best, I used this without the resize part though. Thanks!

Comment: This is probably the only functional method on Ubuntu 14.04. There is a visible quality degradation (even removing the `-s 640x480` bit) but the end result is acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

You can try with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ogv output.avi
```

Comment: So far it looks like the move from mencoder did it for me! Funny thing is, it used to convert properly with my script and with Devede. Then I noticed, about since a week ago, it got out of sync.

Comment: *** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.

Comment: This method does not work on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

In terminal type the following,

```
mencoder input.ogv -o output.avi -oac mp3lame -lameopts fast:preset=standard -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:vbitrate=4000
```

- Change the **input**.ogv to the name of you of your ogv file.
- You can also give the name for the output file by altering **output**.avi in the above command.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

using the -idx switch fixed this for me...discussion here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=665836

`mencoder -idx input.ogv -ovc lavc -oac mp3lame -o output.avi`

Comment: Hmm.. unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I'll be trying other stuff too.

Comment: that's odd.  this is why i switched to using ffmpeg to do screen capture.  gtkrecord does weird stuff with the ogv container and you get unpredictable playback across different players.

Answer (score 1):

mencoder is very good at these sort of things. Earlier today I wrote about making screencasts in Ubuntu using recordmydesktop and then converting the ogv files into avi with xvid video and mp3 audio. You can find it at http://binwaheed.blogspot.com/2010/12/creating-screencast-in-ubuntu-linux.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

for me the next combination works

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
ffmpeg -sameq -i /home/xxxx/x.ogv /home/xxx/x.avi
```

more detail here http://linux.bzic.org/cum-fac-screencast-captura-de-pe-monitor-in-ubuntu-gnulinux/

Answer (score 0):

Try [avidemux](http://packages.ubuntu.com/avidemux) [image: Install avidemux]
, it's available in the repositories and has a intuitive GUI.

Comment: It can't open ogv files.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Mobile Media Converter](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.php). It has a really simple GUI but it can do what you are trying to do.