# How to convert .ogv to .avi?

Tags: video, conversion, convert, recordmydesktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Video converter: ogv to avi (or another more common format)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17309/video-converter-ogv-to-avi-or-another-more-common-format)

I'm making tutorials with recordmyDesktop. The thing is that the final file extension is .ogv but I want to convert it to .avi without losing quality. How to do that?