# (Ubuntu 14.04) High Quality .OGV conversion to either .AVI or .MP4

Tags: video, conversion, avconv

Unfortunately, none of the solutions found on this post helped:

**RELATED:** [Video converter: ogv to avi (or another more common format)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17309/video-converter-ogv-to-avi-or-another-more-common-format)

I have a **High Quality** animation (specifically, from Diablo 3) on **.ogv** format and I need to be able to convert it to a more common format which can be used on video editing tools, more specifically, Cinelerra which just closes on attempts to open **.ogv** files, returning as error:

> Aborted (core dumped)

My idea is to simply swap the format **without losing quality**. In order to do so, I used **avprobe** to check the video's information in an attempt to copy it's configurations over to my encoding. The output from **avprobe** is as follows:

```
Input #0, ogg, from 'Cinematic_1_Intro.ogv':
  Duration: 00:02:42.79, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4489 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Data: skeleton
    Stream #0.1: Video: theora, yuv420p, 1280x544, 14 fps, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : ffmpeg2theora-0.28
    Stream #0.2: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : ffmpeg2theora-0.28
      SOURCE_OSHASH   : f29728676ce32de9
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 0
```

For conversion, I'm using **avconv** with the following parameters:

```
avconv -i Cinematic_1_Intro.ogv -c:v libx264 -acodec libmp3lame -vol 360 Cinematic_1_Intro.mp4 -r 14 -crf 0 -b 4489k -s 1280x544
```

I've also tried swapping the **framerate** to **24**, same results. Here is a screenshot of both videos:

http://postimg.org/image/63sxjp3tf/full/

***Note that the image is from a dual-monitor setup with both on 1920x1024, so it may take a while to render.***

On the right we have the original video and, on the left, the converted one. As you can see, the **quality is horrible** and the **colors are all wrong**.

So, what else can I do? I've tried every single thing I could find on the internet and I simply cannot convert this and maintain the quality. I've even tried **ffmpeg** and **mencoder** with all the suggested parameters on the **related** post, but I also couldn't get it converted with enough quality.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that if you really want to import your video into another application for *editing* you would be better to use a lossless video format such as HuffYUV or FFV1 or even lossless h.264 [using -qp 0 rather than -crf 0](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide#LosslessH.264) as you have done. Depends which Cinelerra likes the most.

For *lossless h.264* try the following and see if it is any better than your own results:

```
avconv -i Cinematic_1_Intro.ogv \
       -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -qp 0 -vf scale="1280:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" \
       -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 3 -af 'volume=1.5' -ac 2 \
       Cinematic_1_Intro.mp4
```

A lot of this syntax comes from the current FFmpeg and I have not tested on an older avconv, in particular the scaling and volume changes where I have attempted to reproduce some of your settings...

Comment: Just testet it on Debian using avconv version 11.2-6:11.2-1, and it made my day. Thx a lot! :-)